# how to disable user impersonation in kubernetes?

Tags: security, kubernetes, impersonation, kubernetes-security

Is there a way to disable impersonation in Kubernetes for all admin/non Admin users?

```
kubectl get pod --as user1
```

The above command should not provide answer due to security concerns.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless all your users are already admins they should not be able to impersonate users. As `cluster-admin` you can do "anything" and pre-installed roles/rb should not be edited under normal circumstances.

The necessary Role to **enable** impersonation is:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: impersonator
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["users", "groups", "serviceaccounts"]
  verbs: ["impersonate"]
```

As long as normal users don't have those permissions, they should not be allowed to perform `--as`.

Comment: Yeah you gave me a comprehensive understanding, Thank you.